# Where is the autoexpect command line tool on OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5)

Tags: macos

On a fresh OS X 10.8.5 install, I was surprised to find no `autoexpect` tool.  Where'd it go?

Comment: For future reference, it is also missing from 10.15.7 and 12.2 (and presumably everything else up to 12.2).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To install `autoexpect` you can install the [homebrew](http://brew.sh) version of `expect`:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
brew install expect
```